# can not connect to azure sql dw using azure databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL data warehouse but receiving this error. "com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: SQL DW failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector"

further more it says that "The connection string contains a badly formed name or value. [ErrorCode = 0] [SQLState = null]"

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct connection string to connect to Azure SQL Data Warehouse using Azure Databricks.

```
dwDatabase = "master"
dwServer = "azuresqldw"
dwUser = “azurewala"
dwPass = "*******"
dwJdbcPort = "1433"
dwJdbcExtraOptions = "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=10;"
sqlDwUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dwServer + ".database.windows.net:" + dwJdbcPort + ";database=" + dwDatabase + ";user=" + dwUser+";password=" + dwPass + ";"+dwJdbcExtraOptions
sqlDwUrlSmall = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dwServer + ".database.windows.net:" + dwJdbcPort + ";database=" + dwDatabase + ";user=" + dwUser+";password=" + dwPass
#print(sqlDwUrl)
```

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-in%2Fazure%2Fazure-databricks%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-in%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)

Hope this helps.